# If a daemon.sh executed faild while system booting can cause Linux start failed?

Tags: linux, shell, tomcat

I would like to make tomcat auto start with a non-root user while system booting. I have created a daemon.sh under folder `/etc/init.d` .  And I executed `chkconfig tomcat on`. The linux server is in another city. I access it by ssh. And I cannot reboot server to test it.

The problem is if tomcat start failed while booting, I am afraid that linux server cannot not be start succesfully. That whould be a disaster for me. Perhaps my worry is unnecessary.

How to avoid this problem?

Comment: You could also create a cron job to ensure it's running perhaps, and if not start it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.